# ViewComponent fired but no output appears on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've got a navbar at the top of my ASP.Net CORE site and I'm trying to create dynamic menu options. So far, I'm just trying to replace some of the options on the _layout page with a ViewComponent like I've done in a few other projects.

```
<header>
    <nav class="navTop">
        <a class="logo" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
            <img src="~/Images/logo.svg" />
        </a>
        @{ await Component.InvokeAsync("MainMenu"); }
        @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial"); }
    </nav>
</header>
```

I have my Component View in the folder

```
Views > Shared > Components > MainMenu > Default.cshtml
```

Which looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Home.MainMenuItem>
```

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    
        @Html.ActionLink(item.DisplayText, item.Action, item.Controller)
    
}

And the ViewComponent InvokeAsync looks like:

```
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var x = new DataAccess.Menus.Menu(_context).GetMainMenuItems(User.Identity.Name);
        return View(x);
    }
```

And the DataAccess method is simply returning a List of `MyProject.Models.Home.MainMenuItem` as expected, which has everything populated fine when I step through, but nothing is resulting on the page in the  in place of `@{ await Component.InvokeAsync("MainMenu"); }`!

I've done this before in a few other projects and never had a problem - so I don't know why this could be going wrong. Any ideas?!

It's getting to the view and I can even see it stepping through the `foreach` loop with the correct populated properties so why does nothing show up on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write it like this

```
@{ @await Component.InvokeAsync("MainMenu") }
```

Or directly

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MainMenu")
```

Comment: Haha that's so annoying, I just couldn't see that difference when comparing it with the other ones I'd done. It's because I had it next to the `@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial"); }` - which totally threw me. Thanks for spotting it!