# ASP.NET Core view components returning blank pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a view component I'm invoking like so:

```
@{
    await Component.InvokeAsync("Edit", new { config = new List<EditConfiguration>() });
}
```

It looks like this:

```
// Need to make individual view components for every page
public class EditViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(List<EditConfiguration> config)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Edit/Edit.cshtml", config);
    }
}
```

I've confirmed with breakpoints that the `InvokeAsync` method and `Edit.cshtml` are being entered by the code.

But nothing is actually returned by `InvokeAsync`, the page is just blank. Even if I just change `Edit.cshtml` so that it's some text and nothing else so there's no chance of internal page error. Removed the parameter/model, same thing. It's just not returning anything.

What do I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
@{
    await Component.InvokeAsync("Edit", new { config = new List<EditConfiguration>() });
}
```

To:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Edit",new { config = new List<EditConfiguration>() })
```

Comment: Wow, this worked. This other, similar question from a while back said either should work, but apparently only the second one does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674086/viewcomponent-fired-but-no-output-appears-on-page

FYI to others: You have to do add the @ even if it's already inside a C# code block, such as a using block. Usually putting an @ when you're already inside a C# block throws an error, so that's a weirdly inconsistent behavior

Edit: Just realized the old question also had the double @'s, thus why it worked. My brain skimmed over the second @

Answer (score 0):

Right click on InvokeAsync in the controller and from there create a view it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).